# C# How to get the number of bytes send/received of a notwork adapter

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I would like to get some network statistics in a C# program (FW 4.8 or .NET 5) of a specific network adapter. I know of System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIPStatistics but this is not helpful because it depends on network **interfaces** and not **adapters**. On a Windows 10 machine with Hyper-V enabled, the physical adapters do not have interfaces and are only bridged to a Hyper-V switch.

In the Control Panel GUI the information is available:

[image: Screenshot]

I guess the info could be access using the native IP Helper API somewhere but I could not yet find it.

Does anybody now how to get the statistics or have any code ready to use?

Comment: i would look to see if WMI has it

Comment: yup it does: https://superuser.com/questions/1218962/get-wmic-bytes-received-sent-to-match-count-in-windows-network-status-interface

Comment: Thanks, Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface and Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkAdapter do provide the required numbers; different to the ones in the GUI but close. The only problem left is to tell the adapters apart. They have the names "Intel[R] 82574L Gigabit Network Connection" and "Intel[R] 82574L Gigabit Network Connection#1". How do I get configured name ("LAN" "WAN" in the example) for each?